# iPad - How to get original size of image

Tags: image, ipad, image-size

It is known fact that safari on iPad reduces the dimension of large images automatically to save resource. The problem is I need to get the original size of image through javascript after image load. Is it possible?

Comment: the size is the same. only zoom level is different.